# Powershell: Convert unique string to unique int

Tags: powershell

Is there a method for converting unique strings to unique integers in PowerShell?

I'm using a PowerShell function as a service bus between two API's,
the first API produces unique codes e.g. HG44X10999 (varchars)- but the second API which will consume the first as input, will only accept integers. I only care about keeping them unique.

I have looked at `$string.gethashcode()` but this produces negative integers and also changes between builds. `Get-hash | $string -encoding ASCII` obviously outputs varchars too.

Other examples on SO are referring to converting a string of numeric characters to integers i.e. `$string = 123` - but I can't find a way of quickly computing an int from a string of alphanumeric

Comment: What are the restrictions on the INT that the second process accepts? Positive only? 16-bit, 32-bit, or 64-bit? What are the constraints on the strings that the first process produces? Length? Allowed characters in specific positions? All characters guaranteed to be printable? All guaranteed to be uppercase letters or digits? There are ways to accomplish what you seek, but you need to know the characteristics of your data, and so do we if we are to help you.

Comment: thanks Jeff - the format for the second app is bigint() in mysql and a php app will use them to build links. I would prefer to keep them as positive integers of relatively small size eg. int16 or 32

Comment: To continue from Jeff. Some examples of the string and their integer equivalents would help.

Comment: I have given an example of the string above - whenever I meet the same string I want to convert it to the same int

Comment: You have two options - 1) devise a deterministic procedure for converting an arbitrary string to an integer, but this will conflict with your requirement for small integers or 2) keep a track record of all the identifier assignments to make sure you always re-assign the same integer to the same input string, this will require a database or similar way to keep track of them. Do you have a facility to store the string<->integer assignments?

Comment: One example is insufficient. If COBOL were involved, I'd want the PIC clause for the data; is it AA99A99999, or XXXXX99999, or XXXXXXXXXX, or what? (in COBOL PIC, A is a letter, 9 is a digit, and X is any char - and when discussing issues like this, either a regexp or a COBOL PIC clause is a good way of describing your data.)

Comment: The next question that comes up is whether it's mandatory that the conversion be 1:1, rather than 1:N (i.e., one string converts to N integers, but always the _same_ N integers) - if you can do 1:N, then it becomes easier to restrict the magnitude of the integers.

Comment: @Matt - I'm more-or-less assuming that the correspondence between string and integer can be defined by the querent, rather than being imposed externally.

Comment: Jeff, I understand what you are saying - but the original codes are human generated, they are not so well defined - the conversion does not need any ratio, simply a unique integer. I presumed a  builtin method

Comment: Mathias, can you give an example of option 1 in your comment ? if It works I'd prefer to use that, otherwise I will use option 2 and write out to a datatable

Comment: There are no "built-in methods", not in any language I'm aware of. You'll need to define your own function for the conversion, which is not difficult, but _you need to know the characteristics of your data_. If you can't come up with a way of characterizing your human-generated alphanumeric codes, the only way to manage this without exceeding the 32-bit limitation is to use the database method mentioned by @MathiasR.Jessen.

Comment: understood, thanks Jeff

Comment: How long can the int be that you would accept. Are we talking int size or are we talking it just needs to be numbers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Fowler-Noll-Vo hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function#The_hash) seems well-suited for your purpose, as it can produce a 32-bit hash output.

Here's a simple implementation in PowerShell (the offset basis and initial prime is taken from the wikipedia reference table for 32-bit outputs):

```
function Get-FNVHash {

    param(
        [string]$InputString
    )

    # Initial prime and offset chosen for 32-bit output
    # See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler–Noll–Vo_hash_function
    [uint32]$FNVPrime = 16777619
    [uint32]$offset = 2166136261

    # Convert string to byte array, may want to change based on input collation
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($InputString)

    # Copy offset as initial hash value
    [uint32]$hash = $offset

    foreach($octet in $bytes)
    {
        # Apply XOR, multiply by prime and mod with max output size
        $hash = $hash -bxor $octet
        $hash = $hash * $FNVPrime % [System.Math]::Pow(2,32)
    }
    return $hash
}
```

Now you can repeatably produce distinct integers from the input strings:

```
PS C:\> Get-FNVHash HG44X10999
1174154724
```

---

If the target API only accepts positive signed 32-bit integers you can change the modulus to `[System.Math]::Pow(2,31)` (doubling the chance of collisions, to
approx. 1 in 4300 for 1000 distinct inputs)

For further insight into this simple approach, see [this page on FNV](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) and have a look at [this article exploring short string hashing](http://www.orthogonal.com.au/computers/hashstrings/)

Comment: Perfect! Mathias, please POSIX_ME_HARDER :-)

Comment: It's throwing this error Cannot convert value "2166136261" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32." for the Prime and the offset

Comment: Declare them as unsigned integers